# How to create an instance of a class which has its type stored in a Type variable?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm tyring to make a WPF UserControl as generic as possible. I've defined a base class that all User Controls can inehrit from. I'd like to be able to make it generic by specifying Type Parameters for the UserControl or even the base class but this doesn't seem to be possible.

As a work around I'm attempting to set a Type as a parameter, e.g.:

```
public class UCBase : UserControl
{
    public virtual Type UCType { get; private set; }
    public virtual Type PanelType { get; private set; }

    internal void SetType<TVM, TPanel>() where TPanel : new()
    {
        UCType = typeof(TVM);
        PanelType = typeof(TPanel);

    }
}
```

Later, I need to create an instance a class that `UCType` represents, specifically another user control that knows how to deal with the ViewModel I'm going to pass it.

```
    public ZonesAccordionPanel(List<ViewModelBase> vmItems)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (var item in vmItems)
        {
            var exp = new Expander { Header = new ZoneReport(item) };
            exp.Resources.Add("item", item);
            exp.Expanded += exp_Expanded;

            accordion.Children.Add(exp);
        }

    }


    void exp_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var expander = (Expander) sender;
        var currentItem = expander.Resources["item"];

        // I have my data and I'd like to pass that to a specific UserControl
        // that knows how to deal with that data the way I want

    }
```

How can I make that user control based on the type parameters I set with `SetType<TVM, TPanel>()`?

Is it possible to for me to create an instance of a class that has its type stored in `public virtual Type PanelType { get; private set; }`?

If so, how?

Comment: Have you looked at Activator.CreateInstance? If your `UCType` type is generic (in other words, `UCType<T>`), then you can do `Activator.CreateInstance(UCType.MakeGenericType(new[] { PanelType }), <param[] constructor args>)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Activator.CreateInstance( Type )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)